# Get "trimmed minimum", similiar to Excel TRIMMEAN Function

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to implement a custom function into Excel which returns the minimum of a trimmed data sample.

Two inputs:

- Data
- Percentage, which states how many data points from the original data sample should be excluded

**My first draft (seen below) misses two features right now:**

1. When I use the function and select a whole column (e. g. =TrimMIN(A:A)) it takes takes a long time
2. I need to sort the input Range 'data' before trimming it but the line 'data.Cells.Sort' is not working

Looking forward to get get some ideas on those two issues.

**My code:**

```
Function TrimMIN(data As Range, percentage As Double) As Double

Dim dataNew As Range
Dim dataNewS As Variant

Dim diff, counter, upper, lower, countDataNew As Double

counter = 0


'data.Cells.Sort


diff = Round(data.Count * percentage / 2, [0])

Debug.Print "diff= " & diff

upper = data.Count - diff
lower = diff

countDataNew = data.Count - diff - diff

'Application.Min(data)
'Debug.Print "upper= " & upper
'Debug.Print "lower= " & lower
'Debug.Print "data.count= " & data.count
'Debug.Print "countDataNew= " & countDataNew

Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In data.Cells

counter = counter + 1
'Debug.Print "counter= " & counter

Debug.Print "celValue= " & cel.Value

If counter > lower And counter <= upper Then
'Debug.Print "counter in range, counter is " & counter
If Not dataNew Is Nothing Then
        ' Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc cell to our new range, rng2
        ' this is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)
            Set dataNew = Union(dataNew, cel)
        Else
        ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
            Set dataNew = cel
        End If
End If

Next cel

'Debug.Print "dataNew.count " & dataNew.count

TrimMIN = Application.Min(dataNew)

End Function
```

Comment: _"I need to sort the input Range 'data' before trimming it"_: what kind of sorting do you need? what's the _structure_ of your `Data` range

Comment: My code shown above will trim the data range to a smaller one. Which is fine for calculating the MIN when the data is sorted already (e. g. `data = {8, 7, 6, 5}` --> `data_trimmed = {7,6}` --> `MIN(data_trimmed)= 6`). However, when the data input is not sorted it returns a wrong MIN (e. g.  `data={6, 8, 5,7}` --> `data_trimmed = {8,5}` --> `MIN(data_trimmed)= 5`). Therefore, I guess, the data needs to be sorted in the beginning (ascending/descending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working function.

Ideally it is up to you to place an appropriate range as argument to the funtion...

```
Public Function TrimMin(data As Range, percentage As Double) As Double
  Dim usedData As Variant
  'avoid calculating entire columns or rows
  usedData = Intersect(data, data.Parent.UsedRange).Value

  Dim x As Long, y As Long
  x = UBound(usedData) - LBound(usedData) + 1
  y = UBound(usedData, 2) - LBound(usedData, 2) + 1

  Dim arr() As Variant
  ReDim arr(1 To x * y)

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
  counter = 1
  For i = 1 To x
        For j = 1 To y
              If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(usedData(i, j)) Then
                    arr(counter) = usedData(i, j)
                    counter = counter + 1
              End If
        Next j
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arr(1 To counter - 1)

  Dim diff As Long
  diff = Round((counter - 1) * percentage / 2, 0) + 1

  'use the worksheet function to obtain the appropriate small value
  TrimMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(usedData, diff)
End Function
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)